# Implementing MCLP in OPL (CPLEX)

Tags: cplex, opl

I just started some days ago with OPL and try to solve a MCLP problem. I already tried different approaches and read the documentary, but I still have no idea how to implement the Ni formula and especially how to formulate the first constraint where j runs over Ni as seen in the picture below.

Ni describes if the distance between point i and j is within the service radius. I'm also not sure if Ni should rather be described as a matrix and not as a set.

[image]

I tried various ways of indexing and describing Ni using different datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

```
range I=1..4;
range J=1..3;

int P=1;
int a[I]=[100,100,60,100];
float S=2;

tuple position
{
  float x;
  float y;
}

position Ipos[I]=[<1,1>,<-1,1>,<1,-1>,<-1,-1>];
position Jpos[J]=[<1,0.5>,<1,-0.5>,<-1,0>];

float d[i in I][j in J]=sqrt((Ipos[i].x-Jpos[j].x)^2+(Ipos[i].y-Jpos[j].y)^2);

{int} N[i in I]={j | j in J:d[i][j]<=S};

dvar float z;
dvar boolean x[J];
dvar boolean y[I];

maximize z;

subject to
{
  z==sum(i in I)y[i]*a[i];
  
  forall(i in I) sum(j in N[i]) x[j]>=y[i];
  
  sum(j in J) x[j]==P;
}
```

is a small example

PS:

same question at [IBM Community](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/discussion/mclp-implementation-in-opl?ReturnUrl=%2Fcommunity%2Fuser%2Fdatascience%2Fcommunities%2Fcommunity-home%2Fdigestviewer%3Fcommunitykey%3Dab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7)